# Getting error (No module named 'scipy') for Lora training with Kohya

Tags: dreambooth

Unfortunately I'm not able to train Lora on dreambooth and I'm getting these errors. Does anybody could tell me what's wrong? Any help would be appreciated :)

`The following values were not passed to accelerate launch and had defaults used instead:
--num_processes was set to a value of 2
More than one GPU was found, enabling multi-GPU training.
If this was unintended please pass in --num_processes=1.
--num_machines was set to a value of 1
--mixed_precision was set to a value of 'no'
--dynamo_backend was set to a value of 'no'
To avoid this warning pass in values for each of the problematic parameters or run accelerate config.
2024-01-31 20:03:04.188282: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
prepare tokenizerprepare tokenizer

Using DreamBooth method.Using DreamBooth method.

======================================
oduleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/./train_network.py", line 1012, in
trainer.train(args)
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 804003) of binary: /home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/bin/accelerate", line 8, in
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/accelerate_cli.py", line 47, in main
args.func(args)
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 977, in launch_command
multi_gpu_launcher(args)
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 646, in multi_gpu_launcher
distrib_run.run(args)
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 785, in run
elastic_launch(
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 134, in call
return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
File "/home/igpu/sd/kohya_ss/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 250, in launch_agent
raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:
./train_network.py FAILED
Failures:
[1]:
time : 2024-01-31_20:03:38
host : igpu
rank : 1 (local_rank: 1)
exitcode : 1 (pid: 804004)
error_file: <N/A>
traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html

Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
time : 2024-01-31_20:03:38
host : igpu
rank : 0 (local_rank: 0)
exitcode : 1 (pid: 804003)
error_file: <N/A>
traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html

I tried to train a model through Lora Dreambooth through kohya.

I have 2 RTX 4090 GPU installed.`